# three types of tiles for one Android screen

Tags: android

I want to use three kinds of repeating tiles as background for one Android screen. The following is what I want to achieve as an end result.

[image: Android screen]

Can it be done in Android?

Comment: yes , but you must make layout.

Comment: The answer is: **yes, you can**. Altough I can only see two "tiles" (wood and concrete). The rest are icons or backgrounds.

Comment: There is a shadow falling on the wooden tile. Anyway, I would be really grateful if you can point to me where I can read tutorials on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating three layouts inside the main layout achieves the design.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/woodentile" >


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/woodenshadowtile" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/papertile" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You need three bitmap files in the drawable folder. I will show woodentile.xml as an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/inno_luck_wood_pattern_background"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >

</bitmap>
```

That's it. Doing this results in the kind of design that I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml in drawable folder, and use the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="false"
    android:filter="false"  
    android:gravity="fill" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Then set this file to your background. :)